# UIImageView is not Recognizing Second time Gesture

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, gesture

I have implemented `UITapGestureRecognizer` on `UIImageView`, It is working on first tap. On First Tap, I am hiding that image and starting animation. Once the animations are completed, i am showing the image again. But After setting `setHidden:FALSE`, I am not getting the Tap event of that `UIImageView`.

Following is the code I am using :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

[super viewDidLoad];

defaultDogView= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3, 270, 110, 210)];
[defaultDogView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dog1.png"]];
defaultDogView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self addGestureRecognizersToPiece:defaultDogView];


[self.view addSubview:defaultDogView];
}

- (void)addGestureRecognizersToPiece:(UIImageView *)piece 
{
NSLog(@"in Gesture");
   UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapPiece:)];
[tapGesture setDelegate:self];

[piece addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
[tapGesture release];

UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressPiece:)];
[piece addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];
[longPressGesture release];

NSLog(@"%@", [piece gestureRecognizers]);
}
- (void)singleTapPiece:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
NSLog(@"Image Tapped");

/** Hide the default Image and start the animation ***/

[defaultDogView setHidden:TRUE];

/***Animating the Dog***/
[dogArray addObject:[SpriteHelpers setupAnimatedDog:self.view numFrames:69 withFilePrefix:@"dog" withDuration:(12) ofType:@"png" withValue:0]];
dogView = [dogArray objectAtIndex:0];
//[self addGestureRecognizersToPiece:dogView];



[self performSelector:@selector(callBubbleUpdater) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.5];


}
-(void)showDogFrame{
NSLog(@"%@",[defaultDogView gestureRecognizers]);
[defaultDogView setHidden:FALSE];
defaultDogView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When `view` is `hidden` or its `alpha` component is `zero` that view won't receive any `UIGestureRecognizers`.

I can suggest to use next approach if you need to hide some view (let's name it `touchableView`) but want it to respond to gestures:

1. Create `backgroundView` with the same frame as `touchableView`:

   `UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:touchableView.frame];`
2. Set background color of `backgroundView` to `clearColor`:

   `backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`
3. Reset position of `touchableView`:

   `CGRect frame = touchableView.frame;
   frame.origin.x = 0;
   frame.origin.y = 0;`
4. Disable user interaction of `touchableView`:

   `touchableView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;`
5. Add `touchableView` as subview to `backgroundView`:

   `[backgroundView addSubview:touchableView];`
6. Add appropriate gesture recognizers to `backgroundView`.
7. Add `backgroundView` to view that you want.

Now you can hide `touchableView` but you will still receive gesture recognizers.

I don't test this but I think it should work.

Comment: Yes Nekto, you are right, but here the problem is not because of hiding or showing the image. Even if I dont hide/show, i am unable get the tap gesture for image second time, However everything works perfact on first tap. I dont know what is happening, i am unable to find out the reason behind this.

Comment: You've said :  `But After setting setHidden:FALSE, I am not getting the Tap event of that UIImageView.`. Cannot you said that it works wrong if you don't hide image? I spent 10 mins to write that post =(

Comment: Sorry Nekto, but after posting this, i tried the code without hiding the image, and that time i get to know that it is not because of hiding the image. It seeems to be some other issue.

Answer (score 0):

sure

when UIImageView is hidden. it does not receive any touch events

set alpha zero for uiimageview

Comment: Yes sakrist, you are right, but here the problem is not because of hiding or showing the image. Even if I dont hide/show, i am unable get the tap gesture for image second time, However everything works perfact on first tap. I dont know what is happening, i am unable to find out the reason behind this.